# How to iterate objects in an array into many elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

The answer to this is probably really simple but I just can't see it.

I have an array of objects whose information I want to display in various places. I want to put each question into a section h1, of which I have five. However, the code I came up with just inserts the question of the last object in the array into every section h1, i.e., they all say "Question 5". I can't figure out why. How do I make this print each question into a different section h1?

```
var questions = [
   {question: "Question1", choices: ["A","B","C"], answer: 0},
   //etc. x 5
];

$('section h1').each(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) { 
        $(this).text(questions[i].question);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.each()` callback function gets passed an `index` as the first parameter. You can use that to determine which question to show, instead of having to loop over all of them.

So change your code to:

```
var questions = [
   {question: "Question1", choices: ["A","B","C"], answer: 0},
   //etc. x 5
];

$('section h1').each(function(index) {
    $(this).text(questions[index].question);
});
```

**EDIT:** Adding additional example for how to populate the choices.

You would need to do this by looping over each section, then finding the `h1` and `li`s within that section to populate.

Like so:

```
var questions = [
   {question: "Question1", choices: ["A","B","C"], answer: 0},
   //etc. x 5
];

$('section').each(function(index) {
    var question = questions[index], $section = $(this);
    $section.find('h1').text(question.question);
    $section.find('li').text(function (index) {
        return question.choices[index];
    });
});
```

Comment: The OP wants an index based on array [questions] length , not h1 array list.

Comment: @ProllyGeek: That makes no sense. I believe the OP wants exactly what GregL has given them. Put the first question in the first h1, the second in the second, and so on...

Comment: @MattBurland yes i figured out now it makes sense  , though the question is not properely asked.

Comment: @key Don't forget to accept it if it worked for you (click the outline of a tick next to the answer). And welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: @GregL Will do. Can I ask, how would you then iterate the questions.choices into different li for each section? The same pattern but text(questions[index].choices[index]) doesn't work.

Comment: Ideally, that should be a separate question. But because I am feeling generous, I added code to do that to my answer.